# How can I solve this exercise on iteration in python?

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I'm new to programming and I'm stuck with an exercise, I hope someone can help.
The problem is the following:
1)Write a function that repeatedly asks the user to insert a number and computes the sum of those numbers
2)When the user inserts 0, exit and print the value of the sum.

Now this is the code i managed to write, but if my variable keeps increasing the input will never b 0 and the program will run forever...

```
def mysum():
    n=1
    while n>0:
    n=n+int(input('Insert a value: '))
    print(n)
```

Now when I call the function it keeps addings the sum of the numbers the users wrote, but how can I going on with the 2nd point of the exercise?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're close! Loop forever (`while True`) and `break` when the user gives a `0`

```
def mysum():
    n = 0
    while True:
        new = input('Insert a value: ')

        # validate the new input can be made a number
        try:
          new = float(new)
        except ValueError:
          print('invalid input, try again')
          continue

        if not new:  # or new == 0
            break
        n += new
    print(n)
```

Comment: `n` should probably be initialized to 0; the OP's original code conflated the current input with the running total. (Also, there's the minor issue of breaking on non-integer inputs.)